# How to rename the csv file in java?

Tags: java, file, csv

I want to rename a csv file in java using following code segment, but file is not getting renamed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            File fileToBeRenamed = new File("C:/abc/a.txt");
            File newFileName = new File("C:/abcd/b.txt");
            try {
                fileToBeRenamed.createNewFile();
                newFileName.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            boolean isRenamed = fileToBeRenamed.renameTo(newFileName);

            if(isRenamed)
                System.out.println("File renamed successfully");
            else
                System.out.println("File could not be renamed");
        }
```

Its not throwing any error. but file is not getting renamed.So please help me to do so.

Comment: search for how to rename a file in java, it is same as renaming a csv file.

Answer (score 1):

let's suppose you have a file A(fileToBeRenamed) and you want to rename it to B(newFileName). Then , no need to create "newFileName" file. your code is fine , except the file creation part.

so comment out the lines:

```
try {
        fileToBeRenamed.createNewFile();
        newFileName.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And it will work.
Note: I don't think it has anything to do with file extension(csv/text etc), when both are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to rename a.txt to b.txt, So you don't need create b.txt. If you remove newFileName.createNewFile() will work